# LuceneNet - Any Hadoop/HDFSDirectory implementation?

Tags: azure, hadoop, hdfs, lucene.net, azure-hdinsight

I was wondering as there is a JAVA implementation http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_7_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/store/hdfs/HdfsDirectory.html, if does exist similar library for .NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to create my own implementation since I didn't found a concrete .NET implementation. Here is the source I use to create the Hdfs directory:

- Do a similar implementation as Simple File System Directory acording to your need `SimpleFSDirectory.cs` https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene.net/tags/Lucene.Net_3_0_3_RC2_final/src/core/Store/
- Get the latest `Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce` library found in Source Code/**dev** of codeplex http://hadoopsdk.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#readme.md

and use `IHdfsFile` to access the directory.

```
var client = Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce.Hadoop.MakeAzure(...);    
IHdfsFile fs = client.StorageSystem;    
fs.LsFiles(...); // make sure the dir path end with "/"
fs.MakeDirectory(...);    
fs.Exists(...);    
fs.WriteAllBytes(...);    
fs.Delete(...);
```

and use `HdfsPath.Combine(path1, path2);` to create a path.

**Note** the cost of Hadoop in Azure requires min 2 Head Nodes A3 and 1+ Worker Node... min cost monthly is $714.24 https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/